# Reference request: an example of Bott residue formula's usage

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, fixed-point-theorems, chern-classes, equivariant-cohomology

Could you give me an example of a clear and beautiful application of Bott residue formula in torus-equivariant cohomology (see below)?

I found an example calculating a product of Chern classes on *singular* quadric in section 5.3 of [Edidin, Graham *Localization in equivariant intersection theory and the Bott residue formula*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9508001.pdf), but in singular case one need equivariant *Chow groups* instead of equivariant *cohomology*, and anyway the example is too technical.

---

Let $T=(\mathbb C^*)^n$ be an algebraic torus acting on a smooth complex projective variety $X$ such that there is a finite number of $T$-fixed points of $X$. A technically simple case of Bott residue formula says that for $T$-equivariant vector bundle $E$ with $\operatorname{rk} E=\dim X$ the top Chern class is a number given by
$$\int_X c_{top}(X, E)=\sum_{x \in X^T} \frac{c_{top}^T (x, E_x)}{c_{top}^T (x, TX_x)},$$
where

- the right hand side should be calculated in the quotient field of $T$-equivariant cohomology ring of a point, that is simply
  $$\operatorname{Quot} H_T^*(x)=\operatorname{Quot} \mathbb Q[t_1, \ldots, t_n]=\mathbb Q(t_1, \ldots, t_n);$$
- the $T$-equivariant top Chern class $c_{top}^T(x, V)$ of a $T$-representation $V$ (above it is the $x$-fiber $E_x$ or $TX_x$) is the product of $T$-characters of $V$ as elements
  $$a_1t_1+\ldots+a_nt_n \in \mathbb Q[t_1, \ldots, t_n];$$
- the equality is taken in $\mathbb Q(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ as the summands lie there, but the sum lies in $\mathbb Q$.

So one can derive the formula $\chi(X)=\chi(X^T)$ by choosing $E=TX$, but it is too degenerate. Could you give me an example which is more meaningful but still clear enough? Any reference or idea is also welcome!

Comment: this paper looks interesting https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02539v1.pdf but I still have to study it myself. They apply Atiyah-Bott formula for the problems of additive combinatorics.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the line bundle $E = \mathcal{O}(n)$ on $X = \mathbb{CP}^1$ with the standard action of $\mathbb{C}^*$ by rotation.  The fixed points are $0$ and $\infty$, and the fixed point formula involves a non-trivial cancellation.

This example is somewhat more interesting in equivariant K-theory, where it's computing the character of the representation of $SL_2$ on the global sections.

Answer (score 4):

There is the famous paper by Ellingsrud and Strømme, who apply Bott's residue formula to enumerative geometry:

Geir Ellingsrud and Stein Arild Strømme. [Bott's formula and enumerative geometry](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1996-9-01/S0894-0347-96-00189-0/). J. Amer. Math. Soc. 9 (1996), 175-193